# Migrate a term from sharepoint on-premises to sharepoint online, to have same name & GUID

Tags: development, pnp-powershell, pnp, online, term

I have 2 farms sharepoint on-premises 2013 & sharepoint online. where we use to have a license for a third part migration tool, and we have migrated around 70% of the sites, but still the remaining sites require a lot of redevelopment so we keep them for future migration. and as most of the site collections use a term set, so i have migrate this term set, so now we have 2 identical term sets (on-premises & on-line).

where the terms have the same GUID and label, and other settings.. but today i want to add a new term, so i add it to our on-premises farm, but now **i want to migrate or to recreate this term inside the online term set, where i want the online term to have the same GUID & label as the source on-premises term**, so can i do so using PnP? i need the term to have the same GUID, as when we migrate the reaming sites, the metadata columns will be linked using the term GUID and not the term label.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that we cannot keep the same GUID of the terms as the on -premise term when creating terms in SharePoint online.

We can download a copy of the import file, edit the import file by using your term set values and import the terms from the csv file in SharePoint online.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Import term sets.](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/import-term-sets-168fbc86-7fce-4288-9a1f-b83fc3921c18)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.. i am already aware of the import/export, but seems these will work on the term set level.. now as i mentioned i already had migrated the term sets and all its terms,,, but now i need to migrate a single term inside existing term set.. also i am not sure how the migration tool has actually migrated the terms and preserve their GUIDs.. so this means that there must be a way to preserve the GUIDs.. is this correct?

Comment: i found this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpterm?view=sharepoint-ps which mentioned that we can not create term an supply the GUID for it...

Comment: We can create the term but we cannot keep the same GUID for the term in SharePoint online.

Comment: i do not think your point is 100% correct as using this command `New-PnPTerm -Name "Active IT" -TermSet "T Group" -TermGroup "Customers" -Id "53385e78-e4c3-4f26-baac-bf7c832ec7d2" -Lcid "1033"` i am able to create the term with the same GUID !!!

Comment: It is very happy that the issue is resolved.

Comment: Great to hear that, @SharePointTestDev ! Please mark the most appropriate answer as a solution that resolved Your problem (accept via green check mark) so the question will be closed and resolved. If none of these answers resembles Your approach, please provide answer Yourself! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [Hybrid Taxonomy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hybrid/plan-hybrid-sharepoint-taxonomy-and-hybrid-content-types), which will replicate your term store with SharePoint Online. The GUIDs and names will be identical.

Comment: i do not want to over complicate the issue, as i already have 2 copies of the term sets one inside online and the other inside on-premises.. so there is not any manual/simpler appraoch to copy a single term from on-premises to on-line?

Comment: You took the hard approach. The easiest approach is to use hybrid Taxonomy which copies up the entire Term Set and Terms with the same ID, then pushes them back down to on-prem.

Comment: i might consider the approach you are proposing if i am building the online term sets from scratch.. but in my case i already have terms sets migrated from on-premises to online.. and now i need to migrate a single term only...

Comment: Well, the approach I outlined is when you come from _on-prem_ and need ot duplicate your taxonomy in SPO. But yeah, you're otherwise out of luck.

Comment: not really out of luck,, as using this command `New-PnPTerm -Name "Active IT" -TermSet "T Group" -TermGroup "Customers" -Id "53385e78-e4c3-4f26-baac-bf7c832ec7d2" -Lcid "1033"` i am able to create an online term which have the same GUID and name as the on-premises one... so i am able to migrate single terms using this command,,, and this is what i was searching for !!!